# Segmentation fault on Mono marshalling Vector3f struct

Tags: c#, c++, linux, mono, interop

Our Unity3D game uses a C++ DLL for a portion of our framework and its all been working fine for us in Windows. We recently made an attempt to build our game for Linux and ran into a pretty bad hard crash.

I isolated the problem away from Unity3D itself -> It works perfectly fine between Windows and Linux without our C++ library.

I have compiled the library to a Linux lib within a Ubuntu x64 environment.

The game loads into our initial scene fine (Proving Unity3D is okay), but when we load a level that utilizes the library we get a segfault on bad memory when calling one of the library functions with data passed from Unity3D.

I compiled a debug version of the library and ran the game in gdb in Linux to produce the below debug call stack:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff7fd3780 (LWP 7347)]
0x00007fffb42d94da in geom::Vector3f::Vector3f (this=0x1adff9a8, other=...)
    at /mnt/hgfs/WFTO/war-for-the-overworld/CustomPlugins/GameLogic/GameLogic/Source/lib/geom/Vector3f.h:16
16/mnt/hgfs/WFTO/war-for-the-overworld/CustomPlugins/GameLogic/GameLogic/Source/lib/geom/Vector3f.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff6236425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6236425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6239b8b in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff2749f6c in ?? () from /home/ryan/.gvfs/build on strich/Release/Linux/WFTO_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so
#3  0x00007ffff27876e9 in ?? () from /home/ryan/.gvfs/build on strich/Release/Linux/WFTO_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x00007fffb42d94da in geom::Vector3f::Vector3f (this=0x1adff9a8, other=...)
    at /mnt/hgfs/WFTO/war-for-the-overworld/CustomPlugins/GameLogic/GameLogic/Source/lib/geom/Vector3f.h:16
#6  0x00007fffb42db207 in data::LocatedObject::LocatedObject (this=0x1adff920, id=48, clientObject=0x23, 
    ownerPlayerNumber=0, location=...)
    at /mnt/hgfs/WFTO/war-for-the-overworld/CustomPlugins/GameLogic/GameLogic/Source/components/data/abstract/LocatedObject.h:23
#7  0x00007fffb42db75e in data::PhysicalObject::PhysicalObject (this=0x1adff920, id=48, clientObject=0x23, 
    ownerPlayerNumber=0, location=..., bounds=..., orientation=..., collisionType=data::COLLISION_FULL_SOLID)
    at /mnt/hgfs/WFTO/war-for-the-overworld/CustomPlugins/GameLogic/GameLogic/Source/components/data/abstract/PhysicalObject.h:40
#8  0x00007fffb42e443c in data::PropData::PropData (this=0x1adff920, id=48, clientObject=0x23, ownerPlayerNumber=0, 
    location=..., bounds=..., orientation=...)
    at /mnt/hgfs/WFTO/war-for-the-overworld/CustomPlugins/GameLogic/GameLogic/Source/components/data/prop/PropData.h:18
#9  0x00007fffb42b6e0d in data_PropData_new (id=48, clientObject=0x23, ownerPlayerNumber=0, 
    location=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x4208cccd429acccd>, 
    bounds=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x3f666666>, 
    orientation=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x1cb3>)
    at /mnt/hgfs/WFTO/war-for-the-overworld/CustomPlugins/GameLogic/GameLogic/Source/components/data/prop/PropData_export.h:32
```

Its quite clear where the root cause is, based on the above. When calling **data_PropData_new** our library is getting bad memory pointers to some of the params passed in to the function. Here is the C++ function header:

```
extern "C" { 
DLL_EXPORT PropData* data_PropData_new(
    long long id, ManagedReference clientObject, int ownerPlayerNumber,
    geom::Vector3f location, geom::Vector3f bounds, geom::Vector3f orientation)
```

The C# DllImport:

```
[DllImport("GameLogic", EntryPoint = "data_PropData_new", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern NativePropData create(
        long id, IntPtr clientObject, int ownerPlayerNumber,
        Vector3f location, Vector3f bounds, Vector3f orientation);
```

The first thing to notice is that the bad memory is on all the params with type **geom::Vector3f**. Okay great, that's a good lead. Below is the **Vector3f** code for both C++ and C#:

[Vector3f.h (Quite large so I PasteBin'd it).](http://pastebin.com/D5sGBQVH)

[Vector3f.cs (Quite large so I PasteBin'd it).](http://pastebin.com/3bsR26KP)

Its important to note that this library works perfectly fine in Windows. But not Linux. Could it be that the Vector3f data is not being pinned in memory properly under Linux? I have a hunch that there is some Mono InteropServices platform-specific marshalling problems on Vector3f but I'm struggling to figure out why and where.